# spring-boot with h2 database ,can not connect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I am a new on spring boot. I try to use h2 database in a spring boot project, but when I input `http://localhost:8080/h2-console/`, the page only shown

```json
{
    "username": "Invalid Username",
    "password": "Invalid Password"
}
```

I don't know why and how to solve it.

Comment: I have spring.h2.console.enabled=true in application.properties

Answer (score 0):

to use the H2 console you need to configure it in your .properties file

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2console/
```

where `/h2console/` is the path you want to use on the browser so you can change it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

To use H2 you must set username and password in your application.properties file:

```
# h2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

By default, the password for H2 is not set. The password is therefore blank.

Here is a helpful link for more information about Spring Boot and h2 database:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database